# how to exclude(disable) PackageReference's (transitive)dependency in MSBuild?

Tags: xamarin.forms, msbuild, dependencies, nuget

I'm using a package `Xamanimation` which has a dependency of `Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0`( written in its `nuspec` file):

```
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="Xamarin.Forms" version="4.1.0.581479" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
```

---

but I have built the Xamarin.Froms for my own and added the output dll files into my project's reference:

```
  <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Xaml">
      <HintPath>..\thirdparty\xforms\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

according to the [nuget's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files), I add the `ExcludeAssets` attribute(and other tests) to the section of `PackageReference of Xamanimation`:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Xamanimation">
      <IncludeAssets>compile</IncludeAssets>
      <!-- <ExcludeAssets>compile</ExcludeAssets> -->
      <!-- <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets> -->
      <!-- <ExcludeAssets>buildtransitive</ExcludeAssets> -->
      <Version>1.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

but none of them work!

`MSBuild` will always use the trasitive dependency Xamarin.Forms.4.1.0 and ignore my own build ones( in which I have add new classes and use them in the main project so the linking failure is indicating the choosen is the old one).

so what's the correct method to exclude the transitive dependency?

Comment: Have you tried to add dependand package with with `ExcludeAssets="all"`. So like `<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.1.0.581479" exclude="all" />` 
I get it from here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2061 and it makes sense when you read that "nearest" package wins: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spend a whole day learning into this question and finally got a reasonable answer.

so I'd like to post my first LONG answer in stackoverflow by my poor english.

## TL'DR:

the `MSBuild`'s `nuget plugin`'s `ResolveNuGetPackageAssets` target do the evil thing, make a custom target to revert it, go to bottom for the task code.

---

## Studying story

#### first, I made a similar but simpler copy of this problem for studying.

after all, building a xamarin project is too slow,

the demo source is in [github](https://github.com/fatfatson/my.issue.nuget.conflict.git), 
it has four project:

- ConflictLib: the library used both by another lib and main application
- DirectLib: the library used by main application, and is using `ConflictLib`
- MyAppDev: the main application, with above two library as `ProjectReference`
- MyAppConsumer: the other application, using `DirectLib` by `PackageReference`, and `ConflictLib` as `ProjectReference`. to test this situation, I pushed the ConflictLib and DirectLib to `nuget.org`, then made modify to local version of ConflictLib, so I can verify which one is using.

these projects and their relationship are very similar to my origin problem, the key  point is : when application use a library with two different version simutanously, will(should) the local one(ProjectReference or HintPath) win?

for my origin case, xamarin project, it's `No`, so I come to study it.

for the test case, a dotnet core console project, it's `Yes`, so there must be something mysterious in the building process: `MSBuild`, which is a huge system, but now I'm going to dig into it.

#### then, I need a inspecting tool to find out what `MSBuild` does when building a project.

the simple tool is just invoke it in command line, it will display all the `targets` executed. a `msbuild target` is something like `a target in makefile`, and the `tasks` in target are similar to `commands in makefile`, the concept exist with slightly different term in many other system such as gradle,  so it's easy to understand.

but, there are so many targets and tasks, and all they depend on others and interactive though `Property` and `Items`, it's hard to learn which target break my need from the text log.

fortunately, there's an advanced tool for inspecting everything in `MSBuild`: it's called [`MSBuild structured log viewer`](http://msbuildlog.com/), I learn it from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/Home.md).

now build the project with `/bl` option, it will produce a binary log file with full info, open it by the viewer mentioned above:(my origin xamarin project's build log)

[image]

obvious, the `ResolveNuGetPackageAssets` target changes the `Reference` items, which decides the final linked library assembly.

**but why** it doesn't make the wrong decision in the test case? let's view its log:
[image]

got the difference? -- there's no `ResolveNuGetPackageAssets` target!

it's same from `ResolveReferences` to `ResolveAssemblyReferences`, but diff in the nuget part.

while double clicking at `ResolveAssemblyReferences`, the viewer will open the `targets file` in which the target be defined.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

it's still same for both case:

[image]

`ResolveAssemblyReferences` doesn't depend on `ResolveNuGetPackageAssets`, so where does the later come? just click at it, the file opens:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\16.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets

[image]

it overrides `ResolveAssemblyReferencesDependsOn` and add the `ResolveNuGetPackageAssets` to dependency of `ResolveAssemblyReferences`.

the last question: why the above `NuGet.targets` file not appear in the test case? it could still answered by the viewer's `Evaluation` section:

[image]

clearly, this file is not imported because a property `SkipImportNuGetBuildTargets` set to true. after a simple search, I confirmed it's the default value in test case: it's set in [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/055027b26dc18cf4d192140c5fc8047c3d2dea57/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets#L17). but in xamarin case, it's not set and means `false`, so all the things happened.

#### finally, I have to figure out some measures to fix the problem.

first of all, I won't add the `SkipImportNuGetBuildTargets` property to xamarin project, because I think it's a framework design and maybe has a great impact on others, I just want to fix a little, specific problem.

I decide to add a custom target immediately after the `ResolveAssemblyReferences`, remove the `Nuget's Xamarin.Forms` and add my own ones -- just revert what `ResolveNuGetPackageAssets` does.

the task code is simple (only just after I have written, actually it cost me lot of time to search for grammar/builtin function/etc and test):

[image]

notice how the `Remove Item`(see [msbuild doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019)) works (and not work: the commented lines), I still don't understand it exactly, but it did work!